# change css using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Javascript._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ClearValue() {

            var txtName = document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID %>');
            txtName.value = hidden.value
                txtName.className = ''
                txtName.className = 'TextBox2'

            }
        }
    </script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
  .TextBox
{
    width: 150px;
    border: Solid 1px MistyRose;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

 .TextBox2
{
    width: 300px;
    border: Solid 6px MistyRose;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.3em;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:ClearValue()" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

here am trying to change the Css for the  text box  using javascript.

which is not happening any idea how to solve this  issue

thanks

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you have Language A (.NET here) dynamically outputting Language B (JavaScript here), the first step at debugging should be to examine the generated code. Then you question becomes either "Why is .NET outputting this instead of that?" or "Why does this JavaScript fail?" — and that is a lot easier to answer (and lets a lot more people answer since it doesn't require knowledge of both languages).

Answer (score 2):

Your script probably stops because there is no `hidden` value anywhere.

You also have an extra `}` at the end of the script.

This should work:

```
function ClearValue() {
   var txtName = document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID %>');
   txtName.className = '';
   txtName.className = 'TextBox2';
}
```

Thought this will also work well in modern browsers (though broken in older versions of IE, thanks [@David Dorward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/david-dorward)):

```
function ClearValue() {
   var txtName = document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID %>');
   txtName.setAttribute('class', '');
   txtName.setAttribute('class', 'TextBox2');
}
```

You really should try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which makes this kind of thing a doddle:

```
function ClearValue()
{
   $('<%=txtName.ClientID %>').toggleClass('TextBox2');
}
```

Comment: Using `setAttribute` will not work well. It is broken in older versions of IE.

Comment: @oded: jQuery=bad, especially when having to debug one of the many current bugs.  Then your version is automatically different from the hosted version.  Then when they make a new feature and don't patch your previous issue...horribad.  As you said the problem is probably because of the extra `}` or  `hidden.value`.  The lack of `;` also could be causing problems.

Comment: @vol7ron - Are you suggesting that jQuery is badly broken and should never be used? Can you back this up?

Comment: I'm saying that if you do anything advanced, you'll come across bugs... many bugs - recently, I was doing something simple with a JS slideshow that worked in everything except IE8.  The only solution I had was to fix it myself and the moment you have to go into the code and fix it, it takes away the major advantage of the package, which, in my opinion is the caching.  -- While everyone is pushing jQuery, the real solution, IMHO, is to further the development of ECMAScript itself.  Having something with less overhead, native to browsers, that takes less code is the best hope.

Comment: While I say this, the simplicities of the language don't have problems, but why use it if you're doing something simple?  it may be likely that I adopt `jQuery` in the future; but as for now, I'm still waiting for it to evolve just a little bit more.  Until that happens, I'll probably remain re-inventing the wheel, which I'm not ashamed of, as I rather know what it takes to do/make/modify something, than be handed it w/o knowing the intricacies.

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
txtName.setAttribute("class",'TextBox2);
```

Comment: The `className` property (used in the original question) is better supported than `setAttribute`

Answer (score -1):

```
             txtname.setAttribute("className", newClass); //For IE; harmless to other browsers.
```

From http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=134282

Comment: Using the `className` property (as the original question already does) instead of the `setAttribute` method avoids the need to hack older versions of IE in this way.